# How to grab Foreign Key from query string and add it to the new record of database?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

I'm very new to **ASP Net Core**. My project will hold directors. Each director has a page that shows a list of his/her movies.

I have two classes. Movie:

```
public class Movie
{
    public int MovieId { get; private set; }
    public int DirectorId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Year { get; set; }
}
```

And Director:

```
public class Director
{
    public int DirectorId { get; private set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string Bio { get; set; }
    public List<Movie> Movies { get; set; }
}
```

---

I have an Index page that shows the **list of Directors**. Please take a look at it:

[List of directors (Index.cshtml)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FVKJb.png)

As you can see, I've put an "Add Movie" button besides each director. By clicking on it, You will navigate to a page and you can add a movie. But the problem is I want to pass the director Id to that page. Movie class has a foreign key named "DirectorId". Each new movie must automatically add the director's Id in its "DirectorId" field.

I already put DirectorId in the url, By this line of code in the Index.cshtml:

```
<a asp-page="./Movies/Create" asp-route-DirectorId="@item.DirectorId">Add Movie</a>
```

---

So, I want you to show me how to pick the DirectorId in the URL (As you see in the picture below) and add it to the new movie's "DirectorId" field.

[Add new movie page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/igVUI.jpg)

(Please see this picture above for a better understanding)

Comment: so what is problem? it seems you are doing right. when create page will invoke get method you will get directorid in get method parameter. you must have get method on create page should like this : public IActionResult OnGet(int id).

Comment: @user13422309 Yeah I think I should use OnGet. But this is my very first project. I already tried but failed. I'll try again with "public IActionResult OnGet(int id)" you said. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have made an example based on your codes and needs.

***Index View***

```
<h1>Index</h1>

<p>
    <a asp-page="Create">Create New</a>
</p>
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Directors[0].Name)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Directors[0].Country)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Directors[0].Bio)
            </th>

            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model.Directors)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Country)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Bio)
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a asp-page="./Movies/Create" asp-route-DirectorId="@item.DirectorId">Add Movie</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

***Create View***

```
<h4>Movie</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4">
    <form method="post">
        <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Movie.DirectorId" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="Movie.DirectorId" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Movie.DirectorId" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Movie.Title" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="Movie.Title" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Movie.Title" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Movie.Year" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="Movie.Year" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Movie.Year" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

***IndexModel***

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    public IList<Director> Directors { get; set; }

    public void OnGet()
    {

        Directors = new List<Director>
        {
            new Director{ Name = "AA", Country = "C1", DirectorId = 1, Bio = "XXXXX" },
            new Director{ Name = "BB", Country = "C2", DirectorId = 2, Bio = "XXXXX" },
            new Director{ Name = "CC", Country = "C3", DirectorId = 3, Bio = "XXXXX" }
        };

    }
}
```

***CreateModel***

```
public class CreateModel : PageModel
{

    public Movie Movie { get; set; }

    public void OnGet(int DirectorId)
    {
        Movie = new Movie { DirectorId = DirectorId };
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Hope it can help you.

Comment: the main point was `OnGet(int DirectorId)` in **CreateModel** code.

Comment: @S.Serpooshan Aye. Thanks.